# Multiple files sharing 1 Main instance

Tags: python, oop

Multiple files in a project

- db.py
  Setup and handle firebase_admin connection
- model.py
  Abstract class for model CRUD
- session.py, config.py...
  Some classes extend models
- main.py
  Import files, coordinate them

main.py basically:

```
import db

class App():
    ....

main = App()
main.db = db.start(options)
```

model.py basically:

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC
    class Model():
        ...
        @abstractmethod
        def gen_key(self):
            pass
    
        def create(self):
            main.db.users_ref.set({
                self.gen_key() : self.output_data()
            })
```

but model.py cannot access main
I tried

```
global main
main = App()
```

in main.py, doesn't work.

Tried import main.py in model.py, got circular import error

Do I need to pass main to every single instance? Seemed so troublesome

I make model.py because I'm trying to make different parts of firebase more consistent. I learn this kind of things from PHP yii framework, it's for MySql, but make sense to me so I copy that kind of things.

You can see a gen_key in Model. I hope every "Table" have a gen_key method.
For example, Session.gen_key will return self.date
Config.key will return self.type+"_"+self.date
With that, I can just define the gen key rule, and run

```
record = new Session
record.date = today
record.save
```

Then things would automatically organise themselves in firebase

Comment: What exactly do you need model.py to do? Could you put it in a function/object?

Comment: @TheOtterlord I guess I can, I'm just trying to make it things extend model.py, so everything can be more standardised
I'll put more detail in the question to explain

Comment: I'm afraid Python does not allow access to the root module, so your only options really are to put it in a funcion/object or put the code in the same file.

Comment: @TszFungLi The way to solve this is to move everything out of your *main.py* script and put it in a separate *app.py* module. The new module would create an instance of `App` and also have a `run` function that did the rest of the initial setup. The main script would then contain only `if __name__ == 'main': from abc.app import run; run()`. And the other modules would do `from abc.app import myapp` to get access to the `App` instance. (NB: for the imports to work properly, it's important to put **all** your modules in a package and then have `main.py` beside it in the same directory).

Comment: maybe you should send it as argument `Model(main.db)` when you create it. If you create it inside `App()` then `Model(self.db)`. It will be more readable`.